# haml/RoR: How to make a substring of a rails label have %i applied to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to apply an html tag to a substring of a rails `form_for` label, in the following context.

```
=f.label  :question_7, "The Portrait of a Lady _ Henry James, an American author."
```

When I would like to do the following

```
"<i> The Portrait of a Lady </i> _ Henry James, an American author."
```

I tried using the `#{}` string interpolation operator and putting `%i` in there but that doesn't work and neither is it an intuitive solution. I similarly tried to vanilla HTML tags in the string which also doesn't work. If I wrap the tag in quotes, it just places the tag itself in the string, and if I don't, the view blows up saying it doesn't expect a `<` brace which makes sense cause its haml.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `html_safe`.  I'm sure there are other ways using `content_tag` as well.

```
= f.label :question_7, "<i>The Portrait of a Lady</i> _ Henry James, an American author.".html_safe
```

Or, use a block:

```
= f.label :question_7 do
  %i The Portrait of a Lady
  _ Henry James, an American author
```